# Escaping slashes and tabs

Tags: bash, awk

Trying to split a line with two-bytes `\t` delimiter, faced with strange behaviour

```
a) $> echo '1\2' | awk -F'\' '{print NF}'
2

b) $> echo '1\2' | awk -F'\\' '{print NF}'
2

c) $> echo '1\2' | awk -F'\\\\' '{print NF}'
2

d) $> echo '1\\2' | awk -F'\\\\\\\\' '{print NF}'
2 # splits by `\\` (two bytes) only with 8 slashes

e) $> echo '1\t2' | awk -F'\\\\t' '{print NF}'
2 # splits by `\t` (two bytes) only with 4 slashes
```

It seems that there are two reductions taking place:

1. `\\ -> \` : awk gets half a number of slashes as a `-F` param value. If true, **what's the rule**? Note that I'm **not** using C-escaped string (`$''` notation)
2. awk itself makes `\\ -> \` as is described in the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html)

What's happening here?

Comment: In `awk` you need to double escape your pattern (regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash has no special meaning to the shell when it's inside single-quoted strings; the shell only treats it as an escape character in double-quoted or unquoted strings. So all the reductions are being done by `awk`, not `bash`.

The `-F` option is essentially equivalent to the `-v` option with the variable `FS`, so

```
awk -\\'
```

is like

```
awk -v FS='\\'
```

According to the [AWK Manual](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~renzo/doc/awk/nawkA4.pdf):

> awk processes the values of command line assignments for escape sequences (see Section 8.1
>   [Constant Expressions], page 57).

That means it's like having the following assignment in the `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\\"} ...'
```

The first backslash escapes the second one, so it assigns a single backslash to the variable.

However, it's not *precisely* equivalent to substituting that assignment. In the case of an odd number of backslashes, if you were to write something like

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\\\"} ...'
```

the third backslash escapes the following double-quote, preventing it from ending the string (resulting in an "unterminated string" error). Since there are no actual double quotes when the variable is being assigned using `-v`, there's no quotes that would be escaped. The extra backslash in `-v` is simply treated literally, since there's nothing after it for it to escape.

A further issue is that the value of `FS` is treated as a regular expression. Regexp *also* uses backslash as an escape character, so another level of reduction takes place.